# Grails - Linkedin user as Spring security user

Tags: facebook, grails, twitter, spring-security, linkedin-api

I was wondering if someone has experience with linkedin authentication in his grails application.

A user should login with his linkedin credentials (in the future twitter, facebook etc.) and I would like to handle this user as normal spring security user.

After the user is logged in I'll be able to enrich his profile with his linkedin settings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails have a set of plugins for different authentications: [core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) + set of extenstions for different auth providers ([openid](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-openid), [twitter](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-twitter), [facebook](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook)). As I see it don't have a plugin for LinkedIn authentication, but core plugin is very flexible and extensible, so you can easily add functionality for LinkedIn, if you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn uses OAuth for authentication and has a [REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide). You could use the grails openid plugin for that as mentioned by Igor